# Why I can decrease the process's priority by using nice() function with a typical user permission(except ROOT) in linux?

Tags: linux, process, priority, nice

As I understand every user in linux can change the every process's priority by using nice and renice commands. Also I know that the all users just can increase the priority of processes and the only user that can decrease this priority is ROOT.
When I test this in Terminal environment using these commands everything was OK. Mean's that when I want to decrease the priority of process the system issues the "permission denied" text message.
As I know too by default all processes runs with priority `0` .So when I want to set an process's priority by a negative number, the system must issues an error text. When I run this C language program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
void main()
{
int n=10,r;
r=nice(n);
while(1)
    printf("Test);
}
```

I expected that the system shows an error But program runs with no problem! Although the program runs by a typical user permission.
I want to know why when I want to decrease the process's priority using renice command according to what was expected the system shows error, but when I want to decrease process's priority by using `nice()` function the programs doesn't issues any error?
Is this sentence `All users just can increase the priority of process and the only user that can decrease this priority is ROOT.` correct?

Comment: Maybe, you mean "increase niceness"? Niceness of a process is an opposite concept to priority. All processes may decrease their processor usage (== increase its niceness, == descrease the priority), but only root processes may eat more than before.

Comment: yes,exactly my question is about niceness.you write "All processes may decrease their processor usage, but only root processes may eat more than before."can you explain that,please?I couldn't understand this correctly .

Comment: It's a security decision: to make Denial of Service impossible, I think. Users do need to increase priority of processes, but some malicious users may use this to bring a system down, so only the root (a really trusted user) is permitted to do it.

Comment: yes, but why when I use the `nice()` function in my program, I can decrease the process's priority(Although I have my typical user!)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azad, you're NOT able to reduce the nice-value; you simply chose not to check the result of what you're doing.  Check the content of r after you try to apply a negative increment.  It will be -1, which means your attempt failed.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/resource.h>
void main()
{
    int n=10;
    (void)setpriority(PRIO_PROCESS, 0, n);
    sleep(60);
    while(1)
        printf("Test");
}
```

After setting the process priority to required level, delay by 1 mins so that we can check altered priority in top/ps command. Check this link, http://linux.die.net/man/2/setpriority